# How can i use C++11 explicit templates to reduce binary size?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am new to the concept of explicit templates, and I'm having troubles in using it and seeing any difference in the binary size.
The simple code i wrote goes like this:

comp.cc:

```
  #include "comp.h"

    using namespace std;

    template <typename T>
    int compare(const T& x, const T& y)
    {
        return x < y ? 0 : 1;
    }


    int func()
    {
        compare(10,9);
        compare(1.5, 7.8);
    }
```

comp.h:

```
template <typename T>
int compare(const T& x, const T& y);
```

main.cc:

```
#include "comp.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern template int compare(const int&, const int&);
extern template int compare(const double&, const double&);

int main()
{
    compare(10,9);
    cout << compare(1.5, 7.8) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, not matter if I compile the code with or without the explicit definitions, the size of the binary remains the same.
I guess I am missing something simple, but could not find what it was.

Comment: Yes, you're missing something simple: explicit template declarations have absolute nothing to do with the binary size on modern implementations, where the linker will automatically eliminate duplicate template instances during the link phase. That's what the linker is for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Wouldn't it have an impact on binary size if no one called  ̀compare` (nor `main`, nor `func`)? Then explicit declaration would make binary size bigger because it would generate the code for `compare` while this code would not be generated without the explicit declaration?

Comment: So what do I get from using this feature, if the linker does this job for my anyway? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: What are "explicit templates" supposed to be? It is not even clear why would you expect a difference in binary size (difference  compared to what?).

Comment: The only thing you get from this feature only matter for very, very large, complex, C++ code base, saving the compiler the trouble from burning CPU cycles instantiating the same template in each and every translation units. The saving in compilation time are typically very small, but sometimes with a huge amount of C++ code that needs to be compiled every little bit of savings helps.

Comment: @VTT, compared to not using explicit templates.
You can read here more about explicit templates (under the "Class instantiation section"): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, good. It seems like i got the wrong idea about how this optimization works. So the linker anyway makes sure that the binary does not contain multiple instantiations of the same template function?

Comment: @omer There is nothing named "explicit templates" there. Maybe you've meant "explicitly instantiated templates"?

Comment: @VTT you can use the terms explicit instantiation and extern template class interchangeably.

Comment: This is required by C++. `int compare<int>(const int &, const int &)` is an ordinary function. No different than any other function. A single function must always have the same address, same pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually reduce the code size via explicit template instantiation, however, you need a more complex use case: Given you have a template class as defined in your code of file `comp.cc` and declared in your file `comp.h` and you want to use that class with common instatiations (template parameters) in *more than one executable*, then you can

1. explicitly instantiate the commonly used templates,
2. bundle this object code into a shared object (dynamically linked/shared library) and then
3. use these instantiations from your executables by linking the shared library.

In contrast, if you would use the template instatiations directly in the code of your executables (by including files that also contain the template definitions and not only their declarations), then you would have several (equal) instatiations of your template, one in each executable — yielding a larger object code size in total.

As an example, your explicit template instatiations would go to `comp.cc`. Note that I renamed the function from `compare` to `less`, as just saying 'compare' is not really verbose (how do we compare?) as well as I changed the return value from `int` to `bool`:

```
#include "comp.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename T> bool my_less(const T& x, const T& y)
{
    return x < y;
}

// explicit instatiations
template bool my_less<int>(const int& x, const int& y); // you may omit <int> here
template bool my_less<double>(const double& x, const double& y); // you may omit <double> here
```

The declaration from `comp.h` is similar to yours:

```
template <typename T> bool my_less(const T& x, const T& y);
```

All this will be compiled and linked using the following `Makefile`. Note that I use GNU Make on a Linux system, so if you use a differnt system, your approach might differ here:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11

LDFLAGS += -L.

comp.o : CXXFLAGS += -fPIC

libmy_comp.so : comp.o
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $<

main1 main2 : LDLIBS += -lmy_comp
main1 main2 : libmy_comp.so
```

In essence, this implements the part described as 'put the template instantiations to the shared library `libmy_comp.so` and let the executables `main1` and `main2` resolve undefined references to the template instatiations by linking that library'.

Finally, the `main1.cc` would do:

```
#include "comp.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    my_less(10,9);
    cout << boolalpha << my_less(1.5, 7.8) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And similarily, `main2.cc` would be:

```
#include "comp.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << my_less(10,9) << "\n";
    cout << my_less(1.5, 7.8) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in this example, the `extern template bool my_less<int>(const int& x, const int& y);` is not needed: It can be used to suppress implicit template instatiations, but this is not needed here, since the code of `main1.cc` and `main2.cc` only include the declaration but not the definition of the template functions, so the compiler is not able to generate the code anyway.